# Compress Javascript Options Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, reduce

I've inherited a website and am trying to compress some badly written script. One particular section updates the options in a select field based on other selections. It takes the numeric values from two other select fields in order to update the number of possible options on a third field.

Here is the code in question:

```
    var value = parseInt(first_value) + parseInt(second_value);
    if(value == 1){
        var newOptions = {"0": "0", "1": "1",};
    } else if(value == 2){
        var newOptions = {"0": "0", "1": "1", "2": "2",};
    } else if(value == 3){
        var newOptions = {"0": "0", "1": "1", "2": "2", "3": "3",};
    } else if(value == 4){
        var newOptions = {"0": "0", "1": "1", "2": "2", "3": "3",  "4": "4",};
    } else if(value == 5){
        var newOptions = {"0": "0", "1": "1", "2": "2", "3": "3",  "4": "4", "5": "5",};
    }
```

It goes on like this all the way up to value == 30 so it ends up being a lot of code and I am convinced there is a way to reduce it down.

I've tried a few solutions myself which failed entirely, so thought I'd turn to the community to see if anyone has any ideas?

Comment: Seems like a loop from first to second and shoveling them into an object as string keys/vals would be the easiest approach, although there are others. Curious what didn't work with what you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick and easy way. By setting the iterator `x` to -1, we can use `++x` in the `while` loop. Explicit `Number` casting (`+val`) is probably overkill, but handy if the value for `val` is coming from an input or other HTML element

```js
const getOptions = val => {
  let base = {}, x = -1;
  while (++x <= +val) base[x] = x.toString();
  return base
}

newOptions = getOptions(5);
console.log(newOptions)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
   const foo =(value) => {
    let newOptions={0:'0'}
    for (let i = 1; i < value+1; i++) newOptions[i]=i.toString()   
    return newOptions
   }

   console.log(foo(30))
```